# GET запрос и Content-Length

Tags: http

Подскажите пожалуйста:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#page-30

3.3.  Message Body:

> Присутствие тела сообщения в запросе сигнализируется    полем
> заголовка **Content-Length** или Transfer-Encoding. Запросить
> сообщение    кадрирование не зависит от семантики метода, даже если
> метод     не определяет использование тела сообщения.
>
> Наличие тела сообщения в ответе зависит как от     метода запроса,
> на который оно отвечает, так и от кода состояния ответа
>
> Наличие тела сообщения в ответе зависит как от     метода запроса,
> на который оно отвечает, так и от кода состояния ответа.    Ответы на
> метод запроса HEAD никогда не включают тело сообщения, потому что
> связанные     поля заголовка ответа (например, Transfer-Encoding,
> **Content-Length** и     т. Д.), Если они присутствуют, указывают только то, что их значения было бы, если     бы методом запроса был
> GET.

Подскажите, правильно ли я понимаю, что из этого можно сделать вывод, что при запросе GET по http 1.1 и ниже сервер ВСЕГДА ОБЯЗАН отправить http-заголовок Content-Length* ?

*за исключением кодов ответа 204(non content), 304(Not Modified) и все информационные 100-199 и за исключением присутствия в присланных http-заголовках - заголовка Transfer-Encoding: с параметром chunked.

Comment: Неправильно, так как существует ещё `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, который обозначает тело неопределённой длины (в том числе бесконечной) и с которым использовать Content-Length одновременно нельзя. Собственно, Transfer-Encoding и так уже упомянут в процитированном куске

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо! Немного скорректировал вопрос, то есть получается, что + за исключением присутствия в присланных http-заголовках - заголовка Transfer-Encoding: с параметром chunked  ?